# What does String formatter "<<<&" in Informix 4GL code mean?

Tags: string-formatting, informix, 4gl

I am reading through a legacy 4GL script. In the report section I came across the following:

```
int_type_variable USING “<<<&”
```

I understand this is supposed to convert the integer into a String using the String formatter.
According to [IBM Informix page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.dapip.doc/ids_dapip_0128.htm),

**<** : This character left-justifies the numbers in the display field. It changes leading zeros to a null string.

**&** : This character fills with zeros any positions in the display field that would otherwise be blank.

The int_type_variable is generally 4 digit. I'm confused what it is supposed to do.

I would be grateful, if someone could explain with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the What or Why, a `USING` utilising `"<"` generally indicates that the developer did not want any excess space between the number and whatever was to its left, normally a title or label for the number you are looking at.  So in your case, your report might be saying ...

```
Number of Records Found: 1
```

as opposed to say ...

```
Number of Records Found:    1
```

You might say that is not so bad with an expected maximum value of 9999 but say expected maximum value was 99999999999 then if you did not use `"<"` then you might end up with ...

```
Number of Records Found:           1
```

that is a big space between the number and its label and the possibility that the report reader would not interpret the label as belonging to the number.

You would not use `"<"` if you wanted the digits to align vertically.  Then you would most likely be using `"#"` instead.

The `"&"` is used to indicate what to do if value is zero.  In this case it is saying that if the value is 0 to display a single 0 ...

```
Number of Records Found: 0
```

If you had `"<<<<"` then no value would be displayed ...

```
Number of Records Found:
```

or if you had `"&&&&"` then leading zeros would be displayed...

```
Number of Records Found: 0001
```

Also your link wasn't to an Informix-4gl reference.  You can use the Genero link in this instance http://4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-fgl-manual-html/#fgl-topics/c_fgl_DataConversions_format_numbers.html for some more examples.  I don't think we have added any characters to the 4gl syntax in this area.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clearly defined, but the idea is that the number should be left-justified, and if it is zero, the zero digit should be displayed.  You mention that you saw this in a report, presumably as part of a PRINT statement.  You could easily explore what it does with the DISPLAY statement (outside a report):

```
MAIN

    DEFINE i INTEGER

    FOR i = -10 TO 1000 STEP 5
        DISPLAY "==", i USING "<<<&", "=="  # Optionally drop the "==" strings
    END FOR

END MAIN
```

You could experiment with alternative formats to see what the differences are, such as:

- `"<<<<"`
- `"-<<<"`
- `"-<<&"`
- `"####"`
- `"###&"`
- `"---&"`
- `"-##&"`
- `"-&&&"`
- `"-###"`
- etc.

You could try them all at once with a single DISPLAY statement, or compile the program repeatedly, or pass the format string to a function which does the display work, or …

If you must do it with a report, then you can write a simple report and test it:

```
MAIN

    DEFINE i INTEGER

    START REPORT test_formats

    FOR i = -10 TO 1000 STEP 5
        OUTPUT TO REPORT test_formats(i)
    END FOR

    FINISH REPORT test_formats

END MAIN

REPORT test_formats(i)

    DEFINE i INTEGER

    OUTPUT
        TOP MARGIN 0
        BOTTOM MARGIN 0
        LEFT MARGIN 0
        PAGE LENGTH 1

    ON EVERY ROW
        PRINT COLUMN  1, "==", i USING "<<<&", "==",
              COLUMN 11, "==", i USING "-<<<", "==",
              COLUMN 21, "==", i USING "-<<&", "==",
              COLUMN 31, "==", i USING "####", "==",
              COLUMN 41, "==", i USING "###&", "==",
              COLUMN 51, "==", i USING "---&", "==",
              COLUMN 61, "==", i USING "-##&", "==",
              COLUMN 71, "==", i USING "-###", "=="

END REPORT
```

<sup>***Warning: No I4GL compiler was consulted about the validity of any of the code shown!***</sup>